# Number of group homomorphisms from $Z_2\times Z_2\to Z_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism, ring-homomorphism

My reasoning is: there are four elements in $Z_2\times Z_2$, they are all divisors of $2$. This means that they must be sent to elements of order $2$ or $1$. There are only two elements of these orders in $Z_4$, plus the fact that we need the identity element $(0,0)\in Z_2\times Z_2$ to be sent to the identity $0\in Z_4$. So there are $2^3=8$ different homomorphisms.

Is this reasoning correct? How about ring homomorphisms?

Thanks.

Comment: There are only 3 elements of order $2$ in the first group, and only one in the second. You mean to say "dividing 2". And then note that the three elements of order 2 on the LHS are not independent: once you know where to map two of them the third is their sum so goes to the sum of the images. If you tidy up these you'll get the answer.

Comment: Yeah right, I make the correction.

Comment: So basically the elements $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, whenever they are sent to some elements in $Z_4$, univocally determine the element $(1,1)$ and therefore we only have $2^2=4$ group homomorphisms? How about ring homomorphisms?

Answer (score 2):

Using kernels to find homomorphism,

As, normal subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} $ are, $<(0,0)>,<(1,0)>,<(0,1)>,<(1,1)>,\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} $.

For $<(0,0)>$ as kernel, there is no homomorphism .

For, $<(1,0)>,<(0,1)>,<(1,1)>$ as kernels, there are three non-trivial homomorphism , each one for each respective kernel.

For $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} $ as kernel,  there is a trivial homomorphism.

If you are taking about ring homomorphism, then there is one trivial ring homomorphism , as $\bar{0}$ is idempotent in  $\mathbb{Z}_{4} $

Comment: It's another interesting approach.

Answer (score 1):

$G = C_2 \times C_2$

Let $a \in G$ generate the first $C_2$ and $b$ generate the second. Together $a,b$ generate all of $G$.

A group homomorphism $G \to C_4$ is completely determined by its action on $a$ and $b$ because

- $\phi(1) = 1$
- $\phi(ab) = \phi(a)\phi(b)$

Let $c$ generate $C_4$, as you said $\phi(a) = 1$ or $\phi(a) = c^2$ so there are 2 options for $a$ and 2 options for $b$.

In total 4 possible homomorphisms.